# How to set a variable that vue can read that reacts to swiper's event handlers

Tags: javascript, vue.js, swiper.js

I'm using vue-awesome-swiper and I want to be able to show or hide the Next/Previous buttons on specific conditions.

Specifically, when the slide has reached the beginning, it should show the NEXT button, then when it reaches the end, it should hide that button and show the PREVIOUS button instead.

If possible, I would want it to be set as a variable that v-if can hook on. How do I go about doing that?

**HTML**

```
   <div id="swiper">
<div class="menu-tabs-icon-label">
    <swiper ref="productMenu" :options="swiperNavMenu">
        <swiper-slide>
            <div class="nav-item">
                <a href="#"> Item 1 </a>
            </div>
        </swiper-slide>
        <swiper-slide>
            <div class="nav-item">
                <a href="#"> Item 2 </a>
            </div>
        </swiper-slide>
        <swiper-slide>
            <div class="nav-item ">
                <a href="#"> Item 3 </a>
            </div>
        </swiper-slide>
    <div v-if="reachedEnd" class="swiper-button-prev" slot="button-prev"></div>
    <div v-if="reachedBeginning" class="swiper-button-next" slot="button-next"></div> 
    </swiper>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
  new Vue({
  el: "#swiper",
  components: {
    LocalSwiper: VueAwesomeSwiper.swiper,
    LocalSlide: VueAwesomeSwiper.swiperSlide
  },
  data: {
    swiperNavMenu: {
      freeMode: true,
      slidesPerView: 5.75,
      on: {
        reachBeginning: function() {
          reachedBeginning = true; 
        },
        reachEnd: function() {
          reachedEnd = true;
        }
      }
    }
  },
  computed: {
    swiperA() {
      return this.$refs.productMenu.swiper;
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: What's your version of swiper?

Comment: Swiper version is 4.4.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the answer lies in binding the instance to the variable. The final code should look like this:

```
data() {
const self = this; // this is the line that fixes it all
return { 
  reachedEnd: false,
  swiperNavMenu: {
    on: {
      reachEnd: function(){
        self.reachedEnd=true
      }
    }
  }
 };
},
```

Still thanks to sugars for pointing the way.

Comment: This looks the same as I thought at the beginning.

Comment: but the one you gave didn't expose the variable to the root scope. "const self = this" before the other data is the key that solved this. But still appreciate your guidance. Thanks.

Comment: You're welcome, you can check my [edit history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58618145/revisions), it is correct at the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is related that `reachedBeginning` and `reachedEnd` variables are not defined

```
...
data() {
  return {
    reachedBeginning: false,
    reachedEnd: false,
    swiperNavMenu: {
      freeMode: true,
      slidesPerView: 5.75,
      on: {
        reachBeginning: ()=> {
          this.reachedBeginning = true; 
        },
        reachEnd: ()=> {
          this.reachedEnd = true;
        }
      }
    }
  }  
},
...
```

Comment: Even adding that, it doesn't seem to react to swiper's event. It still remains false (the initial value) even though it has supposedly triggered those two conditions. Additionally, getting this error: that.reachedBeginning

Comment: Can you confirm that the `on` event was triggered?

Comment: It does get triggered, on the condition that i remove the that.reachedBeginning = true; line as it blocks further js code from executing because of this error: [Vue warn]: Error in mounted hook: "ReferenceError: that is not defined"

Comment: Use the arrow function of es6 to point this to the Vue instance

Comment: Sorry, still doesn't react (but the error is gone now since you changed it to 'this' instead of 'that'). I can confirm that the event triggers and the code passed through to this.reachedBeginning = true and this.reachedEnd = true line. Unfortunately, it still doesn't get intercepted by vue.